# angular : Enable button when a variable is stored in localstorage

Tags: angularjs

I would like to disable a button if the localStorage variable 'compute' doesn't exist, and enable it when it exists (the app can create or destroy this variable a few times).
Thanks

```
        <button nav-direction="back" class="button yy" ui-sref="app.result" ui-sref-active="currentNav" ng-disabled="{{bool}}" ng-click="navResult()"> 
          Board
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngDisabled takes an expression as it's argument. You are binding a value by using `{{bool}}` when it should be just `bool`

```
    <button nav-direction="back" class="button yy" ui-sref="app.result" ui-sref-active="currentNav" ng-disabled="bool" ng-click="navResult()"> 
      Board
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-enabled** as follows.

```
<button ng-enabled="localStorage.getItem('compute') === null" nav-direction="back" class="button yy" ui-sref="app.result" ui-sref-active="currentNav" ng-click="navResult()"> 
   Board
</button>
```

You can also use angular-local-storage 
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: `<button>` does not support `enabled` attribute.

Comment: Then need to change it to disable and !== operator